How to round corners in Carbon Bar Chart?
I am creating a simple bar chart in Angular using the IBM Carbon Charts library. How do I make the bars in the bar chart have round corners? I do not see this option in their documentation:
I have tried adding this CSS to the chart, but it did not work:
border-radius: 5px;
Is this possible or do I need to replace the bar SVG with my own custom SVG?

You can't because this charting library uses <path> elements for the bars and you cannot apply border-radius to svg paths.
You can apply it to svg <rect> element, but this library looks like it uses paths and not rects.
